# Fastest way to load terabyte sized json or csv file into mySql using queries?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a terabyte sized json data having almost 200+ million rows.I want to load this data into mysql in the fastest way possible  by paralleizing whereever possible.SPECIFICS: I have tried LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE by converting json to csv file .. But its taking a lot of time too...Is there a better alternative??

Comment: Split the data into multiple files and use `load data infile` on each of the segments.  Then combine the data after it is in the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand that this parallelizes by running multiple files together but even during load data infile ...Can we add parrallelism?